# Spring DataJPA custom query issue:

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I have a setup with JPA (hibernate + postgresql) and MongoDB:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

My Repository Interface is:

```
@Repository
public interface JpaModelRepository extends JpaRepository<ModelEntity, Integer> {
    public ModelEntity findByName(String modelNameSample);
}
```

My Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "model")
public class ModelEntity implements GenericId<Integer>, Serializable {

    ....
    @Column (name = "name_tx")
    private String name;
```

Implementation of the repository interface is auto-generated by SpringData. If I remove the findByName, all works fine in my project. If I leave it I have this in tomcat error log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.getProperty()Lorg/springframework/data/repository/query/parser/Property;
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.toPredicate(JpaQueryCreator.java:163)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryCreator.create(JpaQueryCreator.java:49)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createCriteria(AbstractQueryCreator.java:109)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.AbstractQueryCreator.createQuery(AbstractQueryCreator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery$QueryPreparer.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:59)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:164)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:71)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:269)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:142)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:38)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 85 more
```

Tried to use this documentation but failed for some reason:
[Spring Doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation)

Hope is one of you guys managed to create a custom query (like findBySomeProperty(...)) ...

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
    <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-data.jpa.version>1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-data.jpa.version>
    <spring-data.mongodb.version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-data.mongodb.version>
```

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-multistore-test

I did some maven test combining version on that git repository

Answer (score 1):

The Spring data APIs changed bewteen 1.0 and 1.1 releases, that is why this error. Use the same version for both of your dependencies and it should work.

Comment: Hi Abhinav. You are right. Problem is mongo Api is 1.0.4 Release (latest version I found on http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb) and jpa api is 1.1.2 Release (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem of

```
org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.isCountProjection()Ljava/lang/Boolean;
```

But I resolved it by using a proper combination of jars like

```
spring-data-jpa-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar <BR>
spring-data-commons-1.6.3.RELEASE.jar <BR>
spring-data-commons-core-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar<BR>
hibernate-entitymanager-4.1.12.final.jar<BR>
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.final.jar<BR>
hibernate-validator-4.2.0.final.jar<BR>
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.0.CR2.jar<BR>
```

and using Spring core 3.2.5 version of jars. The problem was solved.

I was also using a proper dialect, i.e. the right driver to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem when trying to use Spring Data JPA + Hibernate + Spring Framework 4.0. The problem is that the Spring Data project doesn't keep-up at the same rate as the Spring Framework project.

I resolve the problem using the proper JAR version combination and excluding any other Spring project, so that those depended JAR could be downloaded correctly and automatically based on the "Spring Data" pom.xml file. Check here all the Spring Data dependencies: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework.data%7Cspring-data-jpa%7C1.6.0.RELEASE%7Cjar

I changed my maven pom.xml file to:

```
    <properties>

    <!-- Generic properties -->
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
    <spring-data.version>1.6.0.RELEASE</spring-data.version>

    <!-- Hibernate / JPA -->
    <hibernate.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate.version>

    <!-- Test -->
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

    <!-- Spring framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>

            ....
</dependencies>
```