# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when trying to access DynamoDB from controller on local system

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb

I have a simple spring application that is trying to connect to AWS DynamoDB. However, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.isLimiting()Z
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.triggerAfterCompletionWithError(DispatcherServlet.java:1276)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:958)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilter(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:          org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.isLimiting()Z
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.PartTreeDynamoDBQuery.getResultsRestrictionIfApplicable(PartTreeDynamoDBQuery.java:86)
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.PartTreeDynamoDBQuery.isSingleEntityResultsRestriction(PartTreeDynamoDBQuery.java:94)
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQuery.getExecution(AbstractDynamoDBQuery.java:50)
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQuery.execute(AbstractDynamoDBQuery.java:288)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:384)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.findByName(Unknown Source)
at org.magnum.mobilecloud.video.repository.VideoController.test(VideoController.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
... 38 common frames omitted

2016-01-25 01:16:40.772  WARN 58449 --- [tp1746257394-20] o.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler   : /video/test

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.isLimiting()Z
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.PartTreeDynamoDBQuery.getResultsRestrictionIfApplicable(PartTreeDynamoDBQuery.java:86)
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.PartTreeDynamoDBQuery.isSingleEntityResultsRestriction(PartTreeDynamoDBQuery.java:94)
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQuery.getExecution(AbstractDynamoDBQuery.java:50)
at org.socialsignin.spring.data.dynamodb.repository.query.AbstractDynamoDBQuery.execute(AbstractDynamoDBQuery.java:288)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:384)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:344)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy56.findByName(Unknown Source)
at org.magnum.mobilecloud.video.repository.VideoController.test(VideoController.java:21)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilter(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:115)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration$ApplicationContextFilterConfiguration$1.doFilterInternal(EndpointWebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

2016-01-25 01:16:40.800 ERROR 58449 --- [tp1746257394-20] o.s.b.actuate.web.BasicErrorController   : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.isLimiting()Z
```

My Repository is as follow:

```
@EnableScan
@Repository
public interface VideoRepository extends CrudRepository<Video, Long>{


public Collection<Video> findByName(String title);


public Video findById(String id);   
}
```

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/video")
public class VideoController {

@Autowired
VideoRepository videoRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/test",method = RequestMethod.GET )
public void test() {
    System.out.println("Matched");
    Collection<Video> videos = videoRepository.findByName("test");
    System.out.println("got video");
    Iterator <Video> iter = videos.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("Video name: "+iter.next().getName());
    }
    }


}
```

Entity:

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "Videos")
public class Video {

private String id;
private String name;
private String url;
private int duration;

public Video() {
}

public Video(String name, String url, int duration) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.url = url;
    this.duration = duration;
}

@DynamoDBHashKey
@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey
public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

@DynamoDBAttribute
public int getDuration() {
    return duration;
}

public void setDuration(int duration) {
    this.duration = duration;
}
}
```

I had tried exposing the repository as a @RepositoryRestResource(path ="/video") and it returned the required JSON. However, I do not understand why using the controller does not work. Thanks in advance for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: It could be because of the version as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529268/spring-datajpa-custom-query-issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data does not currently support DynamoDB, i.e. Spring will not provide a `VideoRepository` implementation. A few different options comes to mind:

- From the sample code, it seems like you have already created some DynamoDB entities. Continue to use them, but implement your own `VideoRepository` bean.
- Switch storage backend to [RDS](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/) and take advantage of [Spring Cloud AWS](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/) (e.g. [Data Access with JDBC](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/spring-cloud-aws.html#_data_access_with_jdbc) chapter in the ref doc).
- One answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240736/spring-data-jpa-repositories-with-dynamodb-and-mysql-dual-datasources) suggests that you take a closer look at [this GitHub project](https://github.com/michaellavelle/spring-data-dynamodb).